# JS calculation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple vat calculator, but there is something funny with one of the calculation. The problem is in the last column, saying moms. e=a + d * 0.25 is correct, but the code below is not. It shows a too big number when calculating.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#submit').click(function() {
    //get cost and check value
    var cost = $('#cost').val();
    var check = $('#checkBox');

    if (cost != null && cost != "") {
        if (cost < 350) {
            //c = a * 1
            $('#total').val(cost);
            $('#toll').val("");
            $('#moms').val("");
        } else {
            if (check.is(':checked')) {
                //c = a* 1.107* 1.25
                $('#total').val((cost * 1.107 * 1.25).toFixed(2));
                //d = a * 0.107
                $('#toll').val((cost * 0.107).toFixed(2));
            } else {
                $('#total').val((cost * 1.25).toFixed(2));
                $('#toll').val("");
                $('#moms').val("");
            }
            if ($('#toll').val() != null && $('#toll').val() != "") {
                //e = (a + d) * 0.25
                var moms = (cost + $('#toll').val()) * 0.25;
                $('#moms').val(moms.toFixed(2));
            }
        }

    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of input elements will always be a string. In most of your code, you're using the "cost" value in such a way that it will be implicitly converted to a number. However, the `+` operator is different, and will preferentially perform string concatenation to addition.

If you explicitly force the cost to be a number when you initialize it, things should work better:

```
var cost = +$('#cost').val();
```

That leading unary `+` operator will force the string value to be treated as a number. Now, of course, if the string doesn't look like a good number, then `cost` will be set to `NaN`, so you should check for that:

```
if (!isNaN(cost)) {
```

That can replace your current check to see if `cost` is not empty.

*edit* Sorry, you'll also need to convert the value of `$('#toll').val()` so that line would look like:

```
            var moms = (cost + +$('#toll').val()) * 0.25;
```

The JavaScript `+` operator really likes strings.

Comment: I didn't understand it. Can you make changes in the code or JS fiddle?

Comment: The changes necessary are right there in my answer, @NikhilAgarwal.

Comment: I understood why ```var cost = +$('#cost').val();``` is done. This is forcing the string value to be treated as number. Now, I didn't get why ```if (!isNaN(cost)) {``` is done, and what to do after calling the function?

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal in your code, you have an `if` statement that checks for `cost != null && cost != ""`. You would change that to `if (!isNaN(cost))`.

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal ah OK, sorry; you probably need a `+` before `$('#toll').val()` too. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Works